# 'arp' command not found when run remotely through Python Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, sh, paramiko, arp

I need to run a script that gets the IP addresses of Qemu VMs running on a Centos Linux Machine. This script is run remotely from another machine.

I am using the python 'Paramiko' library to remotely connect and run the script. However, when I run the arp command to get the IP from the mac address, I get **'arp: command not found'**. However, when I log in to the machine and run the script it runs perfectly. It only fails to recognize the arp command when I run it by connecting through Python Paramiko.

Command used:

```
arp -an | grep aa:bb:cc:dd
```

I tried running this directly through Paramiko, as a part of a python script (through subprocess) and shell script. All result in the same error -  `arp: command not found`
How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: try to use `/full/path/arp`. You can also use some command to check if you run code as the same user as in direct connection.

Comment: Using full path worked, thanks @furas